# Reading CSV with pandas in parallel creates huge memory leak / process zombies

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, memory-leaks

I'm reading +1000 of ~200Mb CSVs in parallel and saving the modified CSV afterwards using pandas. This creates many zombie processes that accumulate to +128Gb of RAM which devastates performance.

```
    csv_data = []
    c = zip(a, b)
    process_pool = Pool(cpu_count())
    for name_and_index in process_pool.starmap(load_and_process_csv, c):
        csv_data.append(name_and_index)
    process_pool.terminate()
    process_pool.close()
    process_pool.join()
```

This is my current solution. It doesn't seem to cause a problem until you process more than 80 CSVs or so.

PS: Even when pool is completed ~96Gb of RAM is still occupied and you can see the python processes occupying RAM but not doing anything nor being destoryed. Moreover, I know with certainty that the function the pool is executing itself is running to completion.

I hope that's descriptive enough.

Comment: is this on an instance?

Comment: no runs on both a desktop and a server. Both Ubuntu

Comment: I believe it is a `pandas` problem since the data frames are loaded into memory and then not flushed until the python process is closed. I have had this issue many times myself.

Comment: Are you also saying that there is no known solution for this? If you've suffered this many times what was your general workflow to solve this?

Comment: Well as someone mentioned this is an I/O related process I have begun using the new `i3` I/O optimized EC2 instances by Amazon. At that point with a 256GB+ RAM box having a few extra DataFrames in memory doesn't matter. You also have the option of potentially optimizing your code. Although I do not know what that entails.

Comment: Unsure if things have changed in the past year, but just adding the close and join solved the same problem for me. My memory usage dropped from 20Gb down to 10.

Answer (score 4):

Python's `multiprocessing` module is process-based. So it is natural that you have many processes.

Worse, these processes do not share memory, but communicate through `pickling/unpickling`. So they are very slow if large data need to be transferred between processed, which is happening here.

For this case, because the processing is `I/O` related, you may have better performance using multithread with `threading` module if `I/O` is the bottleneck. Threads share memory but they also 'share' 1 CPU core, so it's not guarantee to run faster, you should try it.

**Update:** If multithread does not help, you don't have many options left. Because this case is exactly against the critical weakness of Python's parallel processing architecture. You may want to try dask (parallel pandas): http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/